# retrieve image from sql server in picturebox with linq

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

I have saved a picture in database and now i want to retrieve image and set in picturebox with linq

```
private void dataGridViewUser_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
      DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewUser.CurrentRow;

      byte[]  x=(byte[])row.Cells["Image"].Value;

      MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(x);
      picuser.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(ms1);            
}
```

Comment: Ok, great. If you encounter probblems, feel free to ask a question.

Comment: I understand your first sentence, but how is your code related? and where is your problem?

Comment: Why do you mention LINQ? Because you think it is fashionable and yet you don't need it?

Comment: i can't put image from sql server in picturebox,because .net can't  convert type of byte in object